# Proper way of storing Time in Android's SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, time

What is the proper way of storing time to SharedPreferences?
This is what was on my mind, but I get an error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Time to long. What format should I use to store it?

```
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();
long time2 = today;
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putLong("lastUpdated", time2);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: use a long to store date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to maintain the time zone itself, or just the instant in time being represented? If it's the latter, just call [`Time.toMillis`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#toMillis%28boolean%29) which will return a `long`. If you need to preserve the time zone as well, I'd just store the time zone ID in a separate string.

You can then get back to a `Time` later by creating a new instance (with the appropriate time zone) and calling [`Time.set`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#set%28long%29).

(You'll need to figure out whether to pass in `true` or `false` for `ignoreDst` based on your precise context. There's some advice in the documentation.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = null;
preferences = act.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME",
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().putString("TIME", getCurrentTimeDate())
                    .commit();
```

and use this method to get time.

```
private String getCurrentTimeDate() {

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Date instead of Time:

```
Date today = new Date();
long time2 = today.getTime();
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putLong("lastUpdated", time2);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use Time which is part of Android's API?